# slidebox sample in angularjs, or ionic.

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I just want to make like this slide box in my application. [[image: 1]]

I don't want a working code, I just want somebody to give me some hints from where can I start, or how can I implement it ??

Can I use the `slidebox` directive in ionic and add some modification or should I make a new directive.

Please help me. and I'm appreciating any suggestions.

Comment: *I just want to make like this slide box* Which slide box?

Comment: Hey@AlexJolig, I mean that slide box and above that slide box another slidebox containing information. not just one picture. did u get it ??